# Generate stand-alone SVG from Meteor with iron-router

Tags: javascript, svg, meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I want to server dynamic SVG files with templating abilities through Meteor, using Iron-Router.

I first set up a new route:

```
@route 'svg', {
   path: '/svg/:name'
   data: -> { name: this.params.name } # sample data
   layoutTemplate: 'svg'
}
```

And a template:

```
<template name="svg">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
      xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
      xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      version="1.1"
      width="500"
      height="500"
      id="svg2">
  <defs
        id="defs4" />
  <metadata
        id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
            rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
              rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
        transform="translate(0,-552.36218)"
        id="layer1">
    <text
     x="55.067966"
     y="838.08844"
     id="text2985"
     xml:space="preserve"
     style="font-size:108.92150116px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;text-align:start;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;text-anchor:start;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Source Sans Pro;-inkscape-font-specification:Source Sans Pro"><tspan
       x="55.067966"
       y="838.08844"
       id="tspan2987">{{name}}</tspan></text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</template>
```

Then I browse to `http://localhost:3000/svg/foobar` and I get this (in the browser):

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
client/infrastructureViews/svg.html:2: Expected tag name after `<`
<?xml version="1.0" e...
 ^

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

**Question:** How can I tell Meteor or Iron-Router to not generate the surrounding `<html>...` structure and recognize the SVG as a [spacebars top-level element](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars#top-level-elements-in-a-html-file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make IR do that, but you can enter the manual mode and generate the response yourself.

First, tell the router that a certain path will be managed on the server side:

```
this.route('svg', {
  path: '/svg/:name',
  where: 'server'
});
```

Then create a middleware on the server side to manage your response:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice (0, 0, {
  route: '/svg',
  handle: function(req, res, next) {
    var name = req.url.split('/')[1];    // Get the parameter
    new Fiber(function () {              // Packing in Fiber is unnecessary,
                                         // unless you want to connect to Mongo
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain',});
      res.write('Example output');
      res.end();
    }).run()
  },
});
```

Notice that you won't have the templating engine on the server side. The easiest way to remedy this is to put your svg file into the `/private` folder, fetch it as a text asset and then use underscore template format (so `<%= name %>` instead of `{{name}}`) to fill it with data:

```
var template = Assets.getText('file.svg');
var output = _.template(template, {
  name: 'name',
});
```

Comment: I just tried this in Meteor 0.9.0: My browser just keeps refreshing the whole time _before_ even rendering something. `curl` outputs something that looks suspiciously like a regular Meteor website. Do I need to add some package or something?

Comment: Can you clarify how your solution is supposed to work?

Comment: Sure, which part is unclear? In short, you create a middleware that will respond to the client request with the complete SVG file before Meteor can take over and send its HTML wrap.

Comment: I guess it's clear, but I can't get it to work: As described above, the page I try to open, doesn't stop reloading (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/svg/foobar` reloads several times a second) and now I managed to see that before it dies, in the console it says `TypeError: WebApp.connectHandlers is undefined`. `curl localhost:3000/svg/foobar` just outputs the regular Meteor website (`<html>...`).

Comment: Works for me, check out the minimal repo: https://github.com/subhog/stackoverflow-25483299

Comment: Stupid me. I had the the Router code on the client and no surprise that it can't access `Npm` there... While digging through the documentation I found another solution, but I'll post that seperately. Thanks a lot though, without your repo it might have taken me quite some time...

Answer (score 0):

Based on @HubertOG's answer and the [IronRouter documentation](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#server-side-routing) I came up with another aproach, that is IronRouter only, by using both `where` and `action` options:

```
Router.map ->
  @route 'svg',
    path: '/svg/:name'
    where: 'server'
    action: ->
      svgTemplate = Assets.getText('svg/drawing.svg')
      svg = _.template(svgTemplate, { name: @params.name })
      @response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml'})
      @response.end(svg)
```

*The respective SVG file **must** be stored in a subdirectory of `/private` and `../` doesn't seem to work.*